# ASP.NET Gridview RowUpdating event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

**HTML Page:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="Grd_Threshold" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                    GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Records." PageSize="8"
                    AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="Grd_Threshold_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="Grd_Threshold_RowCommand"
                    DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowCancelingEdit="Grd_Threshold_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="Grd_Threshold_RowEditing"
                    OnRowUpdating="Grd_Threshold_RowUpdating">
                    <Columns>                        
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CLNAME") + ", " + Eval("CFNAME") +" " +Eval("CMNAME")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doctor" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOCTORNAME")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("INAME")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Form" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IFORM")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Strength" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ISTRG")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ORDERDATE")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRICE")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Qty" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Eval("QTY")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QTY")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("USERID")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**CS Code:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Title = "Dashboard";
                if (!Master.Page.IsPostBackEventControlRegistered)
                {
                    BindGrid();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.WriteLog(ex);
            }
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                if (SessionUtility.DashboardRecords == null || SessionUtility.DashboardRecords.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    string WebServiceUrl = SessionUtility.WebServiceUrl + "/GetAllOrders/";
                    JsonArrayCollection ReqResponse = Common.GetWebServiceResponse_MultipleValues(WebServiceUrl, "GET");
                    DataTable Patients = Common.ConvertJsonArrayObjectCollectionToDataTable(ReqResponse);

                    SessionUtility.DashboardRecords = Patients;
                }

                if (SessionUtility.UserRight != "1")
                {
                    //Grd_Threshold.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    Grd_Threshold.AutoGenerateEditButton = false;
                }
                else if (SessionUtility.UserRight == "1")
                {
                    Grd_Threshold.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
                }
                Grd_Threshold.DataSource = SessionUtility.DashboardRecords;
                Grd_Threshold.DataBind();
                UpdatePanel1.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.WriteLog(ex);
            }
        }
```

Hi All,

In above written code only EDIT event is being fired & that is only once after that UPDATE,CANCEL no event is being fired. What am i doing wrong?All I want to do is change the GridRow Color on the basis of the value entered in QTY field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The event was not firing because of the same IDs that i had given to the Label in each row. Hope this helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your use of `IsPostBackEventControlRegistered` - I havent seen it used before but it seems that probably you are wiping out your update event by `DataBind()` every time in `Page_Load()`.

`Page_Load` is fired every time the page loads which is then changing what the page is doing by resetting the grid.

Try wrapping the control in:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  // bind
}
```

so that it only does this on the first page load.

Comment: Also, and im no exception catching expert, it seems that your try catch blocks are a bit general. This could result in exceptions being swallowed (even though they are logged) and then the program can continue in an unknown state. You could expose security holes or corrupt your own data using general exception handling like this.

Comment: I used IsPostBack property but same thing happened.

Comment: Also when i click the Update link in grid Page_Load event is fired every time but not the RowUpdating event.

Comment: I also tried everything written here http://forums.asp.net/t/1177561.aspx but still no luck.

Comment: Also i noticed one thing if i AutoGenerate the Columns All events are fired without any problems but if i use TemplateField only Edit Event is fired that is only once. Sorry i know i'm posting a lot of comments on my own question.